# Do I really have to addSubView for each child of a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a Mapbox view which I'm setting up then adding as a subview. I thought it reasonable to expect that the child of that view would also be added when the Mapbox view is added. However, it seems that I need to call addSubView for each child of the first view.

Here's the entirety of my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var locationButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var mapView: MGLMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "mapbox://styles/billofbong/xxx/draft")
        mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: url);
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: xxx, longitude: -xxx), zoomLevel: 15, animated: false)
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.showsHeading = true;
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        view.addSubview(buttonView)
    }
    
    @IBAction func onLocationButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
    }
    

}
```

The reason I'm adding the Mapbox view as a subview instead of just having it be the original view in the ViewController is that changing the parameters didn't seem to do anything when it was the active view so I was stuck with the default map parameters.

Here's a screenshot of my storyboard:
[image]

Can anyone shed some light on the addSubView situation? What if I have a bunch of buttons? Do I really have to programmatically add each one? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you already added the views to the storyboard, as you are using IBOutlets.

Comment: @Sweeper the views are in the storyboard, you’re correct, but they don’t appear when run unless I do addSubView()

Comment: Did you input a styleURL in the storyboard's property inspector?

Comment: The button will be in the view hierarchy as a result of the storyboard, but you are  adding the map view with bounds equal to the whole frame, so the button will be behind it and therefore not visible. You should be able to add a `UIView` to your storyboard and set its custom class to `MGLMapView` and then set any desired properties in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @Paulw11 the Map View in the storyboard is type `MGLMapView`--that's all working unless it's the Storyboard Entry Point, in which case I can't change its properties. Is there any way to have the button appear in front of the Map View as it does in the storyboard? I tried `view.bringSubviewToFront(buttonView)` and that didn't change anything.

Comment: If you can't change the map view properties then you have some other problem. The fact that it is the storyboard initial view doesn't matter.

Comment: I deleted the ViewController and put everything into a new one and now it works. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my `ViewController`, added a new one, linked all the IBOutlets, and now it works fine. I must have messed something up with the first ViewController.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you do have to add each button to your view. How should XCode figure out on itself where these elements should be located otherwise?

Comment: I guess I just thought that was the whole idea of children. The button is a child of the view, which is a child of another view. I thought XCode would know where to put them because I dragged them there on the storyboard. Obviously this isn’t unity, but in unity, when you instantiate a prefab, all its children are instantiated with it, attached to it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ah, now I get you! Your issue could be related to missing Layout constraints or misconfigured Auto Layout.

More information:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html